# DocumentDb: Polygon intersection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

From what I can see, there is no way to effective determine if a polygon and a circle intersect in DocumentDb. In fact, can this even be done with two polygons?

[image: Intersection]

Comment: Please provide examples on how these things represented in your database? If they are geospatial, then DocumentDB has some functions that may be of use but none that do exactly what you want. The closest is ST_WITHIN, which will say whether a point is within a polygon. If not geospatial, then you would need to write something as a UDF or stored procedure to calculate it. Some more details about what you are trying to accomplish and your data structures might enable someone to provide you with a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently - DocumentDB's geospatial query support does not support finding the intersection between two polygons.

It does support querying for points within a polygon. An example query looks something like this:

```sql
-- Find all volcanoes within the state boundary 
-- of Washington (represented as a polygon)
SELECT * 
FROM volcanoes v 
WHERE ST_WITHIN(v.Location, 
{ "type": "Polygon",  "coordinates": [[
    [-124.63, 48.36], [-123.87, 46.14], 
    [-122.23, 45.54], [-119.17, 45.95],
    [-116.92, 45.96], [-116.99, 49.00], 
    [-123.05, 49.02], [-123.15, 48.31],
    [-124.63, 48.36]]]}
)
```

Comment: Note you can implement a UDF in JavaScript similar to http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/Intersection.js to extend DocumentDB's capabilities. This would be a scan though.